# Showing Google Maps with coordinates as variables

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am currently looking for a way to display a Google Maps map within my page. So far I can show the map, but I want the coordinates to be variables.

```
My PHP variables are $lat and $lng
```

This is my code so far

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:440px;width:700px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:440px;width:700px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:15,center:new google.maps.LatLng(<VARIABLE>,<VARIABLE>),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(<VARIABLE>,<VARIABLE>)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Title</strong><br>London, United Kingdom<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create JS Object

```
var displayOnMap = {"lat":<?php echo $lat; ?>, "lng":<?php echo $lng; ?>};
```

Then pass it like

```
new google.maps.LatLng( displayOnMap.lat, displayOnMap.lng);
```